# xamarin android project properties

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to make an application in xamarin for android 5.1.1 version.

But i dont know how to change target framework version. I do not have options that i can see in tutorials:

This is my view:
[image: properties]

And i have only Android 6.0 option.
And i do not even have an options:
- minimum android to target
- target android version

What should i do to see that options?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to download build-tools and platforms in your Android SDK for other Android versions.

In Windows:

1. Open Console (Windows + R, then type "cmd")
2. Open the folder: `cd C:\yourAndroidSdkFolder\tools\bin`
3. Run command: `sdkmanager --list`
4. See which packages you need to download, then pass them as arguments to the command, such as in the example below:

`sdkmanager --verbose "platforms;android-16" "platforms;android-21" "platform-tools" "tools" "other packages you want"`